# Differentials in real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

As far as I can tell, higher level calculus comes in two forms: real analysis and differential geometry.  I'm more familiar with differential geometry, but I've been thinking about real analysis lately.

In differential geometry the way we formalize the intuitive notion of differentials is with differential forms.  I've taken one course on real analysis and we didn't cover differentials.  I also skimmed through a couple of real analysis books and didn't find it either (except in one analysis book where it just gave the differential forms definition).  Are differentials formalized by real analysis?  If so, how?  If not, why?

Comment: I welcome someone who knows more correcting me, but the answer you're looking for might be [Gateaux differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative).